# MongoDB import error : Failed: error reading separator after document #1: bad JSON array format - found no opening bracket '[' in input source

Tags: json, mongodb

Here is my json file :

```
{"a":"b"}
```

When i am importing this file in database by this command:

```
mongoimport --db test --collection abc --jsonArray --file ABC.json
```

I got this error :

```
2016-11-10T15:03:39.696+0530    connected to: localhost
2016-11-10T15:03:39.697+0530    Failed: error reading separator after document #1: bad JSON array format - found no opening bracket '[' in input source
2016-11-10T15:03:39.697+0530    imported 0 documents
```

in my console.

There is no '[' symbol in my file. Can someone tell me where i am wrong?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since you included the option [`--jsonArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--jsonArray), you must provide an array: `[{"a":"b"}]`.

If you provide a single document, do not use the option `--jsonArray`.

Comment: I did not provide an array so I deleted --jsonArray. And it worked. Thanks

Comment: It saved my life. Thank you!